# Is it possible to programmatically send a webpage to a specific chromecast while bypassing the extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

My company has several Chromecasts setup around our facility, each displaying a web page with different data depending on where it is set up.  In my database I have a list of Chromecast names and the URL of the web page they are tied to.  In the UI of my application, there is a table displaying this data.  I would like to have a button for each Chromecast, that when clicked could programmatically pass in the name and URL and begin casting that page - bypassing the Chrome Extension pop-up that automatically populates with a list of receivers.

As of now, I am manually opening 10 tabs and casting each to the specified chromecast; clearly a bit inefficient.  I have searched a few hours today but have not found any example of the specific behavior that I'd like to implement.  I am curious if this type of functionality is possible at this time, it would be of great benefit to me.  Thank you!

Comment: Keep in mind that your Chromecast is not actually pulling down a web page at any point - your computer is downloading and rendering the page, then mirroring video of your browser to the Chromecast. That's not to say that a solution to this doesn't exist, but it wouldn't be as simple as "programmatically sending a webpage". You might sooner find a way to automate or perform a macro on your computer to do the process of opening tabs and using the Chromecast extension for you.

Comment: @Jon Thank you for that.

Comment: @Mike Clearly you didn't, you know, read the entire post.  The question was "is this functionality possible?" not "show/write me a code snippet that achieves this functionality".  Do I really have to explicitly mention that I've read the documentation when asking a question on stack overflow?  I figure that much would be inferred.

Comment: I did read the whole post. Most of the time, when people ask "is X possible", they want someone to write X. You've not been on the site quite as long as I have and maybe haven't witnessed quite as many questions. To answer the question, yes, you should mention that you've read the documentation, if you don't want these kinds of comments.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a program in node js that can do that.

Check out:

https://github.com/simllll/stream-tab

Performance can be improved a lot by using

```
"directRenderMode": true
```

Comment: I have a question. I am not able to start any cast with this. it found devices ran application on tv but doesn't load the url and gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

The best I have found to do this is to use AutoHotKey to script the manual procedure. It is a bit fragile, but it usually gets the job done

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).